# Unable to set Read-Write permission for twitter app

Tags: mobile, twitter, permissions, verification, read-write

I'm stuck in a weird issue while creating a twitter app.

Here i'm supposed to build an app with read-write permission through Twitter's Application Management service ( ridiculous service actually :/ ).

So i've created an app so far. But the problem is that, When i'm trying to set the "Read and Write" permission through Permission tab, It's throwing an error saying,
"You must add your mobile phone to your Twitter profile before granting your application write capabilities. Please read https://support.twitter.com/articles/110250-adding-your-mobile-number-to-your-account-via-web for more information"

Then if try i to add a mobile number through my twitter profile,
Again it's throwing an error saying,
"Sorry, we don't have a connection to your carrier yet!"

P.S. I've tried all the major carriers e.g., Idea, Vodafone, BSNL, DOCOMO.

so, plz help me get rid of this issue by any way.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: i belongs to india.
But it doesn't seems to be a country specific issue, If you'll take a look at this, https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/26862

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is workaround for this problem.

1. Install Twitter android app in your mobile
2. Login to your account
3. Under the options menu, select Settings and then select your account
4. Now select Security, this will prompt you to add phone number, then click OK.
5. You will be redirected to a browser page, enter your mobile number there and save.
6. Now you can go back to your account in normal desktop browser and change the access level settings to read and write.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your great efforts guys.
But, It's already fixed by the twitter's own development team for me.

Comment: Its still not fixed yet. I got the same error in July 2014. The workaround given by @manjunath worked.

Comment: actually i contacted the twitter's developer support team. And they had fixed it for my app from their end.